# Html фон кнопки мешает обработчику клика

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

мне нужно вывести ошибку, когда пользователь нажимает на заблокированную кнопку на странице, для этого решил обернуть кнопку в div, а на него повесить слушатель клика. При нажатии на текст кнопки, скрипт срабатывает, но если нажать на фон кнопки - ничего не происходит.

```js
$(".button-wrapper").click(function() {
  alert("ok");
});
```

```css
.cart_but {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #FE0800;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.button-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cart_but:disabled {
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="cart_but" disabled="">
    <span class="cart_but_text">В корзину</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kolyageshko/pen/jOGXbjw

Comment: Можете заменить `disabled` атрибут на `pointer-events: none`, в таком случае клик на фон и обертку будет срабатывать.

Comment: помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button-wrapper').on('click',function(){
alert('bla');
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]